# Converting Javascript object to jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when iam trying to convert javascript object to jquery object like obj = $(obj). The object obj is loosing one of the property values and setting the value as true.if iam using obj[0].Validated its returning the exact values.Please suggest on this.

```
obj = $(obj);
objValue = obj.attr("Validate");
```

Comment: what is obj? is it a true JS object or is it a reference to a DOM element?

Comment: What are you expecting attr("Validate") to return? Are you expecting your JS object to be converted into a DOM object with attributes? Is Validate a property of your custom object or something?

Comment: expecting attr("Validate") = true/false. converting the JS Object to JQuery Object

Comment: This question is going nowhere unless you post some code to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, you basically have an array of objects since you mentioned being able to do:

```
obj[0].Validate
```

This means that when you convert your object to a jQuery object, you're still dealing with an array of objects.

Simply doing `obj.attr('Validate')` will faily because you're not accessing a single object in your array yet.

Consider the following:

```
var x = {obj1 : {Validate: true, SomethingElse: false, AnotherProperty: true}};
var jQx = $(x);

var jQxFirst = $(jQx.attr('obj1'));
```

Here we can see that I have an collection of objects. In order to check my `Validate` property I need to access the individual item in the object collection.

This will now work:

```
console.log(jQxFirst.attr('Validate'));
console.log(jQxFirst.attr('SomethingElse'));
console.log(jQxFirst.attr('AnotherProperty'))
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/48LWc/

Another example using a more familiar notation to indicate how we're dealing with an array:

http://jsfiddle.net/48LWc/1/

```
var objCollection = new Array();
objCollection[0] = {Validate: true, SomethingElse: false, AnotherProperty: true};

var jQx = $(objCollection);

var jQxFirst = $(jQx[0]);
```